# Pandas: Delete rows of a DataFrame if total count of a particular column occurs only 1 time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to delete rows of a DataFrame if total count of a particular column occurs only 1 time

Example of raw table (values are arbitrary for illustrative purposes):

```
print df

     Country     Series          Value
0    Bolivia     Population      123
1    Kenya       Population      1234
2    Ukraine     Population      12345
3    US          Population      123456
5    Bolivia     GDP             23456
6    Kenya       GDP             234567
7    Ukraine     GDP             2345678
8    US          GDP             23456789
9    Bolivia     #McDonalds      3456
10   Kenya       #Schools        3455
11   Ukraine     #Cars           3456
12   US          #Tshirts        3456789
```

Intended outcome:

```
print df

     Country     Series          Value
0    Bolivia     Population      123
1    Kenya       Population      1234
2    Ukraine     Population      12345
3    US          Population      123456
5    Bolivia     GDP             23456
6    Kenya       GDP             234567
7    Ukraine     GDP             2345678
8    US          GDP             23456789
```

I know that `df.Series.value_counts()>1` will identify which `df.Series` occur more than 1 time; and that the code returned will look something like the following:

```
     Population 
           True
     GDP
           True
     #McDonalds
          False
     #Schools
          False
     #Cars
          False
     #Tshirts
          False
```

I want to write something like the following so that my new DataFrame drops column values from df.Series that occur only 1 time, but this doesn't work:
`df.drop(df.Series.value_counts()==1,axis=1,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a boolean list/array by either list comprehensions or using `DataFrame`'s string manipulation methods.

The list comprehension approach is:

```
vc = df['Series'].value_counts()
u  = [i not in set(vc[vc==1].index) for i in df['Series']]
df = df[u]
```

The other approach is to use the `str.contains` method to check whether the values of the `Series` column contain a given string or match a given regular expression (used in this case as we are using multiple strings):

```
vc  = df['Series'].value_counts()
pat = r'|'.join(vc[vc==1].index)          #Regular expression
df  = df[~df['Series'].str.contains(pat)] #Tilde is to negate boolean
```

Using this regular expressions approach is a bit more hackish and may require some extra processing (character escaping, etc) on `pat` in case you have regex metacharacters in the strings you want to filter out (which requires some basic regex knowledge). However, it's worth noting this approach is about 4x faster than using the list comprehension approach (tested on the data provided in the question).

As a side note, I recommend avoiding using the word `Series` as a column name as that's the name of a pandas object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Gustavo!

I just attempted this solution but it unfortunately didn't work.

Below is the latter part of the error:

`//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1802                     raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   1803                 else:
-> 1804                     raise e1
   1805             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   1806                 raise e1

KeyError: 'Topic'
`

Per your suggestion, I changed the value of my column `Series` to `Topic`

Comment: Looks like a key error. Make sure your columns are properly named and that there's indeed a column called `'Topic'`. I just retested my answer and it seems fine. Here's an IPython dump: http://pastie.org/10740631

Comment: Thanks again, @Gustavo. Now getting the following error:

`
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:3: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  app.launch_new_instance()`

Comment: This error is coming from here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/strings.py#L225 I suspect you have some problematic characters (probably `(` or `)`) in your regex. Can you show me what `pat` looks like?

Comment: As expected, there are a bunch of regex metacharacters. I have edited my answer and added another approach (slightly slower) using list comprehension which hopefully works for you. Dwelling on the regex approach would be a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but the current answer doesn't work for any moderately large dataframes. A much faster and more "dataframe" way is to add a value count column and filter out count.

Create the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': 'Bolivia Kenya Ukraine US Bolivia Kenya Ukraine US Bolivia Kenya Ukraine US'.split(),
                   'Series': 'Pop Pop Pop Pop GDP GDP GDP GDP McDonalds Schools Cars Tshirts'.split()})
```

Drop rows that have a count < 1 for the column ('Series' in this case):

```
# Group values for Series and add 'cnt' column with count
df['cnt'] = df.groupby(['Series'])['Country'].transform('count')
# Drop indexes for count value == 1, and dropping 'cnt' column
df.drop(df[df.cnt==1].index)[['Country','Series']]
```